# Converting between event types

Tags: rust, substrate

Is there any clue on how to correctly compare whether event got from `frame_system::Module::events()` is equal to a specific one from current pallets `decl_event!`?

I've tried to match the event from the list with inner `PostCreated` event:

```rust
let events: Vec<EventRecord<<T as system::Trait>::Event, T::Hash>> = SystemModule::<T>::events();
        
events.iter().filter(|EventRecord { event, .. }| {
    matches!(event, RawEvent::PostCreated(_, _))
});
```

But, got an error:

```sh
428 |             matches!(event, RawEvent::PostCreated(_, _))
    |                      -----  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found enum `RawEvent`
    |                      |
    |                      this expression has type `&<T as frame_system::Trait>::Event`
    |
    = note: expected associated type `<T as frame_system::Trait>::Event`
                          found enum `RawEvent<_>`
    = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as frame_system::Trait>::Event` to `RawEvent<_>`
```

Furthermore, if I add `.into()` to the event, I'm getting another error:

```sh
428 |             matches!(event.into(), RawEvent::PostCreated(_, _))
    |                            ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&<T as frame_system::Trait>::Event>` is not implemented for `RawEvent<_>`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<RawEvent<_>>` for `&<T as frame_system::Trait>::Event`
```

I will appreciate any help. Sure that something is wrong with exactly this lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "generic" event type should be defined like this in your configuration trait:

```
/// The overarching event type.
type Event: From<Event<Self>> + Into<<Self as frame_system::Trait>::Event>;
```

This means that we support the `From` trait from the `Event` enum defined in the pallet, and the `Into` trait for `Event` enum in the `frame_system` pallet.

So the conversion can be the following:

- Raw Event -> Generic Event
- Generic Event -> System Event

So:

```
let generic_event: <T as Trait>::Event = RawEvent::MyEvent.into();
let system_event: <T as frame_system::Trait>::Event = generic_event.into();
```

You can then compare this `system_event` to the events you get back from `frame_system::Module::<T>::events()`.

Comment: What about if my Event has generic <T> and looks like `PostCreated(AccountId, PostId)`?

Comment: The steps I describe above shouldn't change. You need to use `into` twice to convert from pallet event, to generic event, to system event. Take a look at Substrate by searching for `last_event` and you will see some functions that do this.